# Restart failed Selenium browser

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker, docker-compose

Sometimes the docker Selenium Hub gives me this message:

`Marking the node http://172.17.0.2:5555 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries`

What I wonder now is:

- Does it come back after some time?
- How can I monitor that and restart the node?

So, if the node has some internals to restart itself, then I would love to know how and which. I like to tune them a bit.

Other side is, that I could monitor this, track the according docker container and restart the single node.

What is possible here?

Big picture is, that I have built up several browser using `docker-compose scale chrome=16`. After some WebDriver actions (yes, I use a proper `::quit()`) the browser just fails / seem to hang.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question (i.e restarting Nodes), take a look at Selenium-Grid-Extras from groupon: https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras

Looks like it might have some features you'd be able to use. Not sure if it can hook into docker or not, though.